# What does this symbol mean in IntelliJ? Lighting symbol on Java class name

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

[image]

What does this symbol mean in IntelliJ? Lighting symbol on Java class name.

I have seen "I" for interface and "C" for a class But first time noticing this lighting symbol.

Comment: https://www.programmersought.com/article/30081575632/

Comment: @luk2302 this link is too good to be a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This icon represents an `Exception` class (a class extending `Exception`).

[image: exception]

You can hover your mouse cursor on any icon in the project view to see the description like this:

[image: description]

[IntelliJ IDEA documentation for 2020.1 version](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2020.1/symbols.html#common-icons) is the last archive copy of the product help that has this reference.

Comment: Thanks This was helpful.